# How to push value of array if defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which has a list of items that will be returned as undefined if none come back and true if it does.

```
resolved = [undefined, undefined, undefined, true, undefined]
```

if there is a 'true' item in the Array how would I push it into a new array?

I have this so far.

```
resolved.map(item =>{

  if(item === undefined){
    console.log(`No resolved issues`);
  } else {
    console.log(`defined`);
  }

} )
```

output:

```
newResolved = [true]
```

```js
resolved = [undefined, undefined, undefined, true, undefined]

resolved.map(item =>{
    
      if(item === undefined){
        console.log(`No resolved issues`);
      } else {
        console.log(`defined`);
      }
    
    } )
```

Comment: `resolved.filter(Boolean)`? `resolved.some(Boolean)`? Welcome to SO!

Comment: Unclear what you actually want. What is the output/other array?

Comment: @epascarello hey, just updated

Answer (score 1):

You are using `map()` incorrectly as you need a `return` every iteration to the new array it creates

What you are really wanting is `filter()`

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, true, undefined];

const res = arr.filter(e => e===true)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` function to filter valid items only.

```js
const resolved = [undefined, undefined, undefined, true, undefined];

const result = resolved.filter(item => item);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're headed down the right path, I think.  This looks like a prime use of the `forEach` method instead of the `map` method.  This will allow you to look at each array value and do something with it.

```
const newArray = []

resolved.forEach(item =>{
  if(item === undefined){
    console.log(`No resolved issues`);
  } else {
    console.log(`defined`);
    newArray.push(item)
  }
})
```